# Should I store my global constants in resources file (.resx) or in classes?

Tags: c#, .net, constants

I have a plenty of them of different form and types. Of course I will not store a bitmap as `const`, and I know about localization strings, but what should I do with other constants?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Put constants that relate to UI display in resources.
- Put "constants" relating to application configuration like connection strings in **app.config**.
- Put constants that relates to program flow in C# classes.